# Java store map in file

Tags: java, arrays, file, dictionary

I have this map `Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();`

as you can see, I want to store an array on the map.

How can I save the map in a file?

I tried this:

```
// Save map in file
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties properties = new Properties();

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    properties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

properties.store(new FileOutputStream("data.properties"), null);

// Load the map
Map<String, String> map_from_file = new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("data.properties"));

for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
   map_from_file.put(key, properties.get(key).toString());
}
```

this is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to class java.lang.String ([Ljava.lang.String; and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

But it works only with a map that stores only strings, and not an array.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: If you just want to write it to a file and read it back, with no specific format requirements, the easiest thing is to use use serialization; `HashMap`, `String`, and `String[]` are all serializable.  Look for `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Be aware that direct object serialization can be even incompatible when you develop your code further (and the data format needs fields added). Having some more control, such as with a properties file is definitely a good approach if you want to store data for more than a cache.